# Why didn't they let the Hastars fight it out and "kill" each other?

Tags: plot-explanation, tumbbad

Towards the end of *[Tumbbad (2018)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt8239946/)*, Vinayak Rao ties multiple dough dolls to himself so as to lure the Hastars, so that Pandurang can get out of the Womb safely. It is also shown that initially the multiple embodiments of Hastar (each for a doll) who fight each other over the dough dolls.

My question:

> Why couldn't they toss a single doll at a time, let the Hastars fight over it and "kill" each other, and do this until all of them are "dead" and then get out safely?

Comment: "Could the film have ended differently" is a trivial "yes", so I've changed the title of the question to reflect what you're actually asking. I hope that's okay.

Comment: @F1Krazy That's fine :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Why couldn't they toss a single doll at a time, let the Hastars fight over it and "kill" each other, and do this until all of them are "dead" and then get out safely?

It is nowhere shown in the movie that embodiments of Hastar which appeared after Vinayak shows two dough dolls, can kill each other.

We only see two of them pushing each other and trying to snatch the dough doll for himself.

During the fight one embodiment of Hastar falls on the protective shell created by the flour encirclement and turns to dust, which gives Vinayak the idea of luring them out of protection.

It only makes sense that embodiments cannot kill each other because they are part of one entity i.e. Hastar but different bodies. Each body wants the food but cannot destroy other body because their mind is one.